# VirtualBox NAT Issue - Able to Ping and Lookup. Unable to Browse

Tags: virtualbox, nat

I have been facing an unusual problem with my VirtualBox NAT settings. I have scoured the Unix SE Forums but was unable to find a similar issue reported. I did find one but it was from 2009 and related to Corporate Proxy.

**Details :**

- Windows 7 Host running VirtualBox 5.1.0
- Multiple Guest OS - Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS (All Fresh Installations)
- Home Network, No Perimeter Firewall
- Using NAT (Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter)
- From the Guest I am able to Ping external FQDDNs. Which means DNS and Ping is working

**Issue : Unable to Browse any Website**

Sometime ago I had played a little with the 'VBoxManage modifyvm' settings in order to solve a Bridging related issue. I think I may have messed up something which is causing my new issue.

I have tried to re-install VirtualBox but it looks like the previous settings are getting saved somewhere which I am unable to remove and unable to 'Reset to Default' the VBox settings.

**Troubleshooting Done :**

Changed Adapter to PCnet Fast3
Tried Changing IPs, DNS

IP : 192.168.10.15
Default Gateway: 192.168.10.2
DNS: 192.168.10.3

**tcpdump Captures :**

While Pinging to Yahoo.com (Getting Replies) :

```
root@localhost anish]# tcpdump -i enp0s3
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
19:28:20.650985 IP 192.168.10.15.45804 > 192.168.10.3.domain: 1534+ A? yahoo.com. (27)
19:28:20.653043 IP 192.168.10.15.35280 > 192.168.10.3.domain: 47054+ PTR? 3.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (43)
19:28:20.661250 IP 192.168.10.3.domain > 192.168.10.15.45804: 1534 3/0/0 A 98.138.253.109, A 98.139.183.24, A 206.190.36.45 (75)
19:28:20.661833 IP 192.168.10.15 > ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com: ICMP echo request, id 3431, seq 1, length 64
19:28:20.942937 IP ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com > 192.168.10.15: ICMP echo reply, id 3431, seq 1, length 64
```

When trying to Browse through Firefox (Gateway sends Net Unreachable ICMP) :

```
19:29:31.562448 IP 192.168.10.15.38893 > 192.168.10.3.domain: 32749+ A? www.google.com. (32)
19:29:31.562562 IP 192.168.10.15.38893 > 192.168.10.3.domain: 48885+ AAAA? www.google.com. (32)
19:29:31.670159 IP 192.168.10.15.52571 > 192.168.10.3.domain: 60173+ A? www.google.com. (32)
19:29:31.670261 IP 192.168.10.15.52571 > 192.168.10.3.domain: 14907+ AAAA? www.google.com. (32)
19:29:35.937594 IP 192.168.10.3.domain > 192.168.10.15.55703: 53252 NXDomain 0/0/0 (43)
19:29:35.937995 IP 192.168.10.3.domain > 192.168.10.15.38893: 32749 1/0/0 A 216.58.196.196 (48)
19:29:35.938025 IP 192.168.10.3.domain > 192.168.10.15.38893: 48885 NotImp 0/0/0 (32)
19:29:35.938371 IP 192.168.10.3.domain > 192.168.10.15.52571: 60173 1/0/0 A 216.58.196.196 (48)
19:29:35.938408 IP 192.168.10.3.domain > 192.168.10.15.52571: 14907 NotImp 0/0/0 (32)
19:29:35.938865 IP 192.168.10.15.33663 > 192.168.10.3.domain: 46127+ PTR? 15.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
19:29:35.940003 IP 192.168.10.15.46468 > kul06s14-in-f4.1e100.net.http: Flags [S], seq 4014962253, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1649927 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:29:35.941228 IP 192.168.10.2 > 192.168.10.15: ICMP net kul06s14-in-f4.1e100.net unreachable, length 36
19:29:35.941377 IP 192.168.10.15.46469 > kul06s14-in-f4.1e100.net.http: Flags [S], seq 613107971, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1649928 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:29:35.941857 IP 192.168.10.15.46470 > kul06s14-in-f4.1e100.net.http: Flags [S], seq 717756838, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1649929 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:29:35.942613 IP 192.168.10.2 > 192.168.10.15: ICMP net kul06s14-in-f4.1e100.net unreachable, length 36
```

Could someone please guide me in resolving this ? Alternatively, is there any way to take VBox to a 'Default Settings' state ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been only troubleshooting VBox related issues since the past couple of days rather than doing any actual work on my Guest VM's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this issue. Actually, its just a temporary fix as of now till I figure out more.

It looks like VBox settings and VM settings are fine, it is my Windows Host network configuration causing the issue.

I checked further and found that even though I was getting ICMP and DNS resolution, my TCP traffic was not working.

I found it by trying to :

```
root@KaliOrc:~# telnet google.com 80
Trying 216.58.199.174...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

Then on my Windows Host I did a :

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Which apparently resolved the issue ! I was able to Browse and test everything as working.

```
root@KaliOrc:~# telnet google.com 80
Trying 216.58.199.174...
Connected to google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Now every time I reboot my Host, I have to reset winsock for my VM's to be able to browse.

If anyone can shed some light on the root cause it would be great because I will be able to work out a permanent solution.

Anyone having similar problems for which the above 'fix' is not working, please go through the below ticket on VBox which has a ton of information :

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13292

Answer (score 0):

On my system, this was caused by the "hardening" for VirtualBox. There was a DLL injected by Sophos into the winsock stack and virtualbox would not support it.

`netsh winsock reset` - was a temporary fix.

But to permanently fix I had to update my machine's root certificate list so that the DLL (a genuine one) was now recognised by virtualbox as valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the first and only forum question which provided a decisive lead to solve my similar problem.

The winsock reset command also worked in my case. 
I had a VirtualBox ubuntu image, ran with Vagrant, for which ssh didn't work.
On further inspection, I noticed that the host network was completely inaccessible from the guest.
2 fixes helped:

1. `config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]` added to the Vagrant file (this option can also be set using VBoxManage), which resulted only in pings working (google.com, security.ubuntu.com).
2. `netsh winsock reset`, which resulted in everything else working.
   I'm currently studying the logs to identify possible issues with the "hardening" towards DLLs.